Importing gzipped CSV files in QGIS
I often receive bathymetry data in a gzipped delimited text file (xyz) and want to open it directly in qgis without extracting it first. Is that possible? According to QGIS 2.18 user manual it seems to be; "Vector data can also be loaded in read mode from zip and gzip archives into QGIS", but I have never managed to import the files directly.

I haven't looked into the current QGIS user manual, but CSV files are not vector data. Although, you can load CSV files as vector layers into QGIS, those are different types of data.

It is possible to make GDAL to read data directly from a gzipped archive so that x, y, and z coordinates are converted automatically into geometries. I do not understand why it does not work with QGIS.
The challenge with opening a CSV file directly from a compressed file is that the user interface for CSV options gets bypassed and user does not see this dialogue for selecting the x, y, and z fields.

A workaround that works with GDAL is to write an OGR VRT file https://gdal.org/en/stable/drivers/vector/vrt.html and read the gzipped data through it.
This is my test data "places.csv" that I gzipped.
name,lat,lon,z,type,population
Aalfang,48.8393882,15.0675236,20,village,410
Abern,48.0556773,13.1533381,20,village,203
Abersee,47.7266536,13.4169871,20,village,320
Abetzberg,48.0839721,14.76567,20,village,260
Abfaltersbach,46.7564042,12.5298515,20,village,616
Absam,47.2965003,11.5051409,20,village,6543
Abschlag,48.6241667,14.8638577,20,village,78
Absdorf,48.4001618,15.9803689,20,village,459

This is the OGR VRT file
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="places3d">
        <SrcDataSource>/vsigzip/places3d.csv.gz</SrcDataSource>
        <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
        <LayerSRS>WGS84</LayerSRS>
        <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="lon" y="lat" z="z"/>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>

Test with ogrinfo
ogrinfo places3d.vrt -al
INFO: Open of `places3d.vrt'
      using driver `OGR_VRT' successful.

Layer name: places3d
Geometry: Point
Feature Count: 8
Extent: (11.505141, 46.756404) - (15.980369, 48.839388)
Layer SRS WKT:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
name: String (0.0)
lat: String (0.0)
lon: String (0.0)
z: String (0.0)
type: String (0.0)
population: String (0.0)
OGRFeature(places3d):1
  name (String) = Aalfang
  lat (String) = 48.8393882
  lon (String) = 15.0675236
  z (String) = 20
  type (String) = village
  population (String) = 410
  POINT Z (15.0675236 48.8393882 20)
...

Unfortunately this .vrt file does not open any features into QGIS.
It is possible to drag and drop the .gz file directly into QGIS but then QGIS does not know how to map the fields into coordinates and the data gets opened as an attribute table without geometries.

Consider writing a question to QGIS user forum or mailing list and ask if the developers think that the issue with the VRT file is a bug.
